# How to keep views from disappearing in wrap_content

Tags: java, android

I have a problem where a view of mine is disappearing in my RecyclerView when the layout of that view is wrap_content. The RecyclerView is match_parent both directions, and uses a LinearLayout that inflates the below xml file. Here is what each piece of the RecyclerView is supposed to look like:
[image: What the view should look like]

And here is the XML for that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/scheduleBlockColor"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/scheduleBlockText"
        android:background="@color/colorCougarRed" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/scheduleBlockText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/scheduleBlockColor"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/scheduleBlockColor"
        android:paddingEnd="0dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:paddingStart="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/scheduleBlockTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:text="@string/schedule_block_time_default"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/scheduleBlockClassName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/scheduleBlockTime"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/schedule_block_class_default"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/scheduleBlockRoom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/scheduleBlockClassName"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:text="@string/schedule_block_room_default"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My question is, how do I keep that colored piece from disappearing when the RecyclerView loads? If I have the parent RelativeLayout above set to match_parent, it works fine. I've tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32088780/view-disappears-after-setting-height-of-gridlayout-to-wrap-content), but haven't had the same success

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the entire RecyclerView?

Comment: post your problematic screen shot also

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Here is the screenshot of it where the color is failing. http://i.imgur.com/APjn11a.png?1

Comment: All of the text is definitely still acting like the block of color is there, which I find weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of the height set on the `<View>`. It gets messed up (even with `match_parent`) by the fact that it doesn't have content. Since the intention is to have a vertical stripe, you could anchor it to the top and bottom of the parent. You already are doing it for the bottom part (kind of, aligning it to the bottom of the text view container), so you only need to take care of the top anchoring:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/scheduleBlockColor"
    ...
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    ... />
```

Comment: Thanks, this was it. I would've never thought not defining the top would matter, especially since it worked in studio.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of padding using layout_margin inside your RelativeLayout.

Comment: No luck with this solution, assuming you mean the RelativeLayout at the top of the XML